# TakesScreenshot in Selenium with Java does not work

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, takesscreenshot

I'm trying to create a function to get Screenshot in selenium, at the end of the tests.
I am passing 3 parameters "Test result", "Message", "True / False" for the user to decide whether or not to take a print.

However, when executing the function call, it does not take the print off the screen, it generates the HTML with the executed steps, but without the print.

**Function**

```
public void escreveRelatorio(boolean status, String msg, boolean printScreen) {

        scenario.write(msg);

        if(printScreen) {
            scenario.embed(((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES), "image/png");
        }

        if(status == false) {
            Assert.fail(msg);
        }

    }
```

**Function call in the middle of the tests.**

```
generic.escreveRelatorio(false, "O número de confirmação foi gerado: " + num, true);
```

Or

```
public void validaNumeroConfirmacao() {

    String num = generic.obterTexto(lblConfirmationNumber).substring(23);

    if(!num.equals("1")){
        generic.escreveRelatorio(false, "O número de confirmação foi gerado: " + num, true);
    } else {
        generic.escreveRelatorio(true, "O número de confirmação foi gerado: " + num, true);
    }

}
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: _O que estou fazendo de errado?_?

Answer (score 1):

Problem with above example is you are not specifying where your screenshot should save.

Your getScreenshotAs() will return byte[] but you are not doing anything with it.

```
File scrfile=((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);    
FileUtils.copyFile(scrfile, new File("/screenshot/SomeUniqueName.png"));
```

Comment: In this case, do I need to save the physical image and then put it in the Report HTML? I didn't quite understand how to put this in my code.